Bootstrap 5 circular background for bootstrap icon
Can I implement a bootstrap icon with circular background area in Bootstrap 5?
Currently I produced this ellipse. I want to implement it circularly


.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.i1{
  border-radius:50%
}
.i2{
  border-radius:9px 9px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css"/>
<i class="i1 bi bi-check-circle green"></i>
<i class="i2 bi bi-check-circle green"></i>



Thanks in advance

surround each icon inside a parent div. I do this by using ul li and giving it a border-radius that is sufficient for the height, border-color, etc.
Please refer my code ther i commented every details I done


.green{  background-color:green; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.round-list { display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 20px;} /*--- to align list one after another --- */
.round-list li { width: 60px; height: 60px; border-radius: 50%;  display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;  border: 2px solid #000; }  /*--- with and height for perfect circle, display flex to align child elemnt to perrfect center (align-items: center; justify-content: center;)  --- */
.round-list li .bi-check {    font-size: 30pt !important; color:#FFF } /*-- to change icon size and color ---*/
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />


<ul class="round-list">
<li class="green "><i class="bi bi-check"></i></li></li>
<li class="green " ><i class="bi bi-check"></i></li>
</ul>  




.rounded-circle bootstrap you're looking for.
Actually that <i> tag is coming that way only. You can try <span class="rounded-circle"><i class="bi bi-check-circle green rounded-circle"></i></span> still that will come that way.
I have added a new div with background red and it is circular.  The container element should be of block property to make it rounded.


.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.btn-circle {
  height: 24px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: #F00;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

<i class="bi bi-check-circle green rounded-circle"></i>
<i class="bi bi-check-circle green rounded-circle"></i>

<div class="btn-circle rounded-circle">
  <i class="bi bi-check-circle rounded-circle"></i>
<div>




Hi. Thank you. The background is in oval shape. I need it circular. Could you help me in this? Thanks

Hi, Thanks again, I need background red to end at white circle itself. Is it possible? Thanks in advance

I have given you enough guidance to take from here.  Good luck.

Sorry if I made you angry Sir.

No, it's not like that.  Guidance should be enough for you. Carry on.

Oh if so is it ok
